# Laravel validate request parameter only if it's availale

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I implement laravel API, for validation I created a separate request file, and I write my validation rules in that and it's working fine. But the issue is I want to validate my request parameter only if it's available in request. Here is my code for that.

**UserFormRequest.php**

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'customer_phone' => 'regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|max:15',
        'customer_email' => 'required|email',
    ]
}
```

Comment: delete `required` and add `nullable` ex  : `'customer_email' => 'nullable|email',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [conditional validation using `sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present):

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'customer_phone' => 'regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|max:15',
        'customer_email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
    ]
}
```

In the example above, the `customer_email` field will only be validated if it is present.